# Python API for querying Google Developer Console?

Tags: android, python, google-api

I want to get the details of one of my Android apps from the Google Developer Console (i.e. the number of installs, and current rating).

I preferably want to do this using Python. I'd prefer not to go down the screen scraping/Beautiful Soup route, so I've been searching for a relevant API. I haven't managed to find one.

My questions are thus:

- Does such a Python-based Google API exist (and if so, what/where is it)?
- If not, are there any other Python-based libraries I could use?
- If not, what would people recommend as a non-Python alternative?

Answer (score -1):

Try out Google dev scraper:

https://github.com/tmurakam/googleplay_dev_scraper

I'm using it and it works really great! You can get the number of downloads of a specific app, ratings and other statistics that you want. Try it out, you will not be sorry!